# 0 to 360 degress constrained rotation mechanism

Tags: mechanisms

I'm looking for examples of mechanisms that can constrain a hub rotating around a shaft from 0 to 360 degrees.  Rotation between 0 and 360 should be free.  Rotation < 0 and > 360 should be stopped.

A few things I think could work but I am not not sure what this is called and searching on Google has not helped.

- a simple pin would allow for 0..(360 - pin_width)
- a spiral would allow hard stops 0..360 but the pin would need to
  float radially.
- a gear set of 2:1 would allow for pins but would add some complexity.

Thanks for any ideas folks might have and/or any names I might be able to use in a Google search.

Comment: You have a hub with a pin in it that is allowed to spin free on a shaft. You can add a stop collar with a 'dog' that stops rotation in either direction by interacting with the hub's pin. If this stop collar is allowed to float a distance equal to the diameter of the pin plus the width of the stop 'dog' (possibly through its own pin and slot in the shaft) then you achieve a 0° -> 360° -> 0° restricted rotation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an axially sliding collar with a helical groove, then the groove can give exactly 0 to 360...

The helix only needs to be sufficient that the ends of the groove don’t interfere.

You could also fix the collar axially and permit the pin to slide the necessary amount...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest mechanism is to have two stopper pins for each direction, on different planes either radially or along the axle. And then have corresponding dogs that retracts when spins in the other direction to engage each pin.