# Restricting rotational movement

Tags: structural-engineering

I'm looking for an elegant mechanism for restricting the movement of the wheel cradle in the picture.

The wheels are intended to be able to swivel around +-5° but not more.

The initial idea is to have some kind of pin and a slot in the front plane. Is there an established way of making the axis itself somehow reduce the swivel?

- The axis needs to be round in shape (no hump); there'll be tightening clips around it
- The forces to the rotational direction are minimal, i.e. just gravity

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate as this answer is adaptable : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/29921/10902

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the link. I wasn't able to find it in my search. Also, textual entries may be suboptimal so I plan to provide my own solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up trying this:

[image]

Pros:

- does not need extra pins / does not change looks

Cons:

- may be difficult to guarantee the groove is always straight down (if the pin is screwed in)

Other suggestions are welcome and considered. :)

Comment: Strength of your "pin", stress raisers?

Comment: @SolarMike Remains to be seen if the pin is strong enough. The spec has "The forces to the rotational direction are minimal, i.e. just gravity". I.e. I'm more concerned about the green pin not being weakened than the nudge breaking. Is there a way you could improve this design?

Comment: I am completely lost on your question and the attempted solution. Can you update your original drawing to include the direction of the wheels to swivel, that the movement to be restricted? Also, what is the "green pin", in relation to the original drawing?

Comment: @r13 I fully agree with you. Cannot really make sense of it myself, either (that was in 2019). Will try, later.